# Are package maintainers allowed names with apostrophes?

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get errors like this from the Debian source build of a released package:

```
Now running lintian...
E: ros-groovy-libfreenect changes: changed-by-address-malformed Jack O'Quin <jack.oquin@gmail.com>, Piyush Khandelwal <piyushk@gmail.com>
```

Is it complaining about my name? Or about having two maintainers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62118/are-package-maintainers-allowed-names-with-apostrophes?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Maintainer) the field must conform to [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt)

From a quick scan it looks like it would work if enclosed in double quotes.  It will take some more reading but 3.1.1 suggests you can do multiple people in one line.

And [REP 127](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#maintainer-multiple-but-at-least-one) allows multiple.  I don't know bloom's merging behavior, but the above RFC suggests it's dooable.

I'd suggest filing a ticket against bloom to put the control file output in double quotes, or escape the open field correctly.

Also to double check about multiple maintainer status for the debian control file.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-04**:
I'll do that. Wasn't sure where to file it. Fortunately, it does not seem to break anything important. I was just curious about the message.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-05**:
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/145